# Why is the Ubuntu desktop download a zip instead of an iso?

Tags: iso

I have tried downloading Ubuntu desktop four times and it is downloading as a zip file instead of an iso file. When I open it it opens in my archive program. Hence I cannot mount it to disk and install it onto my computer. What can I do?